# Extend polymer element - access parent content

Tags: polymer

I have the following polymer:

```
<polymer-element name="popup-element" attributes="popupStyle">
    <template>
        <div class="popup" id="popup" style="{{popupStyle}}">
            <div class="closebutton"></div>
            <content select=".title"></content>
            <br /><br />
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Polymer('popup-element');
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Now I want to extend it in another polymer:

```
<polymer-element name="newfolder-element" attributes="popupStyle" extends="popup-element">
    <template>
        <shadow>
            <span class="title">Utwórz nowy folder</span>
            <input type="text" class="ginput" style="width: 350px; padding: 5px;" placeholder="Nowy katalog" />
            <br />
            <button class="action blue"><span class="label">Utwórz</span></button>
            <button class="action red" id="cancelBtn" on-click="{{closePopup}}"><span class="label">Anuluj</span></button>
            <content></content>
        </shadow>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('newfolder-element');
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Why content between `<shadow>` and `</shadow>` doesn't appear. I want to place content of `<shadow> ... </shadow>` (child element) to `<content></content>` of parent element. How to make it working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [used to be supported](http://blog.quickui.org/2013/11/08/filling-slots-in-shadow/), but due to implementation concerns, [it was removed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/tH9_SMpDbIg/WBfxvY1cfooJ). It will most likely be added in a future revision to the Shadow DOM spec.

**Update**: [Here's](https://github.com/JanMiksovsky/base-template) a possible interim solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This almost makes the extends feature useless for template inheritance! I take a look at all the core-elements and paper-elements, rarely are they reusing templates from their base element. To get around this limitation I have to use a preprocessor like jade to mix-in partials. But if polymer or the spec can support this, it will be much more convenient. A little bit frustrating that I need to spend so much time just to fix something that should be there.